# map struct interface error in SpringBoot with kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, dependency-injection, mapstruct

i converted java spring boot codes to kotlin, now i have error in map struct interface and bean config class

This is my Mapper interface

```
@Component
@Mapper
interface PersonMapper {

    fun toPerson(personDTO: PersonDTO?): Person?
    fun toPersonDTO(person: Person?): PersonDTO?
    fun toPersons(personDTOS: List<PersonDTO?>?): List<Person?>?
    fun toPersonDTOs(personList: List<Person?>?): List<PersonDTO?>?

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        val INSTANCE: PersonMapper = Mappers.getMapper(PersonMapper::class.java)
    }
}
```

and my Bean Config

```
@Configuration
class BeanConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    fun personMapper(): PersonMapper {
        return PersonMapper.INSTANCE
    }

}
```

and my error

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personController' defined in file [D:\Zaban\Server\target\classes\ir\ktcoders\zaban\person\PersonController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personService' defined in file [D:\Zaban\Server\target\classes\ir\ktcoders\zaban\person\PersonService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personMapper' defined in class path resource [ir/ktcoders/zaban/config/BeanConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [ir.ktcoders.zaban.person.PersonMapper]: Factory method 'personMapper' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should remove the `@Component` from the interface, as it's not bringing any value (but it's also not the culprit of error).

It's hard to tell more, but `ExceptionInInitializerError` looks like there is a problem in the `Mappers` class, so provide the code of it, please. Maybe it's not yet initialized and can't find this mapper?